# How to access Environment properties in the beans element of the Bean Definition DSL using Spring 5 and Kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-dsl

I want to define some beans depending on the values of some properties from the application.yml file of a Spring Boot Application. For instance with a `number-of-beans: 5` I build a for loop to create 5 bean instances:

**application.yml**

```
number-of-beans: 5
```

**BeanDsl.kt**

```
fun beans() = beans {
    val n = env.getProperty("number-of-beans")
    for (i in 1..n) {
        bean<String>("string${i}") { "string${i}" }
    } 
}
```

The problem is how to access the environment at that point since the env variable isn't available there. It's funny it is inside the `bean{}` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with Spring Framework 5.0, but I have just added such support via [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/97ee94f4ca7e1d0c6f7e218e0ba8448940b7ba24), this improvement will be available as of Spring Framework 5.1 / Spring Boot 2.1.